# wrapped text in a table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, ieeetran

I write latex with the `IEEEtran` document class, with TexLive 2022.

I would like to have wrapped text in one of a table's cells ("The number of participants") as follows:

[image: expectation]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabualarx,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\captionof{table}{Participation}
\label{tab:example_MRT} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{The number of participants} & \textbf{Destination} \\
  \hline
  $1$  & A \\
  \hline
  $2$ & B \\
  \hline
  $3$ & C\\
  \hline
  $4$ & D\\

  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, the result is as follows.

[image: result]

What code needs to be added so that the words "The number of participants" can be wrapped in two lines?

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic: There's no real need to use the particle "The" in "The number of particants". You can, in fact, make the first column narrower by writing "Number of\\participants", thereby giving more usable space to the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\makecell` from the `makecell` package

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\captionof{table}{Participation}
\label{tab:example_MRT} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  c |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{\makecell{The number of\\participants}} & \textbf{Destination} \\
  \hline
  $1$  & A \\
  \hline
  $2$ & B \\
  \hline
  $3$ & C\\
  \hline
  $4$ & D\\

  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Unrelated but `caption` is not compatible with `IEEEtran`, and your `\captionof` breaks the table caption settings.

Comment: Since you've encased the `tabularx` environment in a `table` environment, there's no need for either `\captionof{table}{...}` or `\noindent`.